# flutter No such module 'FBSDKCoreKit' error

Tags: flutter, dart

I am a beginner at app development.
I am making an app with flutter, and the following error occurred while building with ios.

```
Uncategorized (Xcode): Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): No such module 'FBSDKCoreKit'
/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_facebook_auth-4.3.3/ios/Classes/FacebookAuth.swift:8:7
2

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12.
Exited (sigterm)
```

But I never installed the facebook_auth package.
There is no flutter_facebook_auth in my pubspec.yaml file either.

But I keep getting the above error. Is there any solution?
Thank you for reading.

===============================================================

I did
`flutter clean` -> `flutter pub get` -> `cd ios` -> `pod install` -> run

And following is the result

```
/Users/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/CompressFileHandler.m:109:16: warning: unused variable 'swf' [-Wunused-variable]
        const char swf[3] = {'F', 'W', 'S'};
                   ^
    /Users//development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/CompressFileHandler.m:110:16: warning: unused variable 'swc' [-Wunused-variable]
        const char swc[3] = {'C', 'W', 'S'};
                   ^
    4 warnings generated.
    warning: [CP] Unable to find matching .xcframework slice in 'ios-arm64 ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator ios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst' for the current build architectures (arm64 x86_64 i386).
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    /Users//development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_facebook_auth-4.3.3/ios/Classes/FacebookAuth.swift:9:8: error: no such module 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    import FBSDKCoreKit
           ^
    /Users//development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_facebook_auth-4.3.3/ios/Classes/FacebookAuth.swift:9:8: error: no such module 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    import FBSDKCoreKit
           ^
    /Users//development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_facebook_auth-4.3.3/ios/Classes/FacebookAuth.swift:9:8: error: no such module 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    import FBSDKCoreKit
           ^
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete
    warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Bundle Resources build phase: /Users//Downloads/GoogleService-Info.plist (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/ly/7jxqf41945g08nj820kfkblr0000gn/T/flutter_tools.QgWT3r/flutter_ios_build_temp_diruHeVSi/temporary_xcresult_bundle
Uncategorized (Xcode): Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): No such module 'FBSDKCoreKit'
/Users//development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_facebook_auth-4.3.3/ios/Classes/FacebookAuth.swift:8:7
2

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12.
```

Pod install result is fine.
[This is the part of the pod install result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzCTO.jpg)

=================================================
`pub.dartlang.org/flutter_facebook_auth-4.3.3/ios/Classes/FacebookAuth.swift:8:7 File contents:`

[facebookauth.swift file contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/de478.png)

===============================================

I found following-facebook auth related- messages when i run the app on real android device

[error msg when running on android device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzJZc.png)

Comment: Have you added firebase_auth or flutter_auth_ui packages in your app?

Comment: @TonnyBawembye Thanks to your reply. um.. I've added ```flutterfire_ui``` Is this the reason!!?

Comment: Okay, probably the flutterfire_ui, depends on flutter_facebook_auth in case you were wondering where the package came from.

Comment: I would suggest you perform a flutter clean, then flutter pub get. And then go ahead and run pod install then try running the app again.  Usually such an error should be due to missing pods. and also, does the app work fine on Android? you can try that out.

Comment: @TonnyBawembye Thank you TonnyBawembye. I did ```flutter clean ``` -> ```flutter pub get``` -> ```cd ios``` -> ```pod install```
But the result is same.
And this app works fine on Android... Noway T.T

Comment: I had the same error. It works fine when I run with my iphone. But when I try to run with simulator, I have No such module 'FBSDKCoreKit' error.

Comment: @Nero Same. Works fine with real iphone7, but error with simulator. hm...

Comment: @Nero I still have another problem but I solved this question. See my own answer

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this error by doing

1. remove Podfile.lock and Pods
2. update Podfile with `platform :ios, '12.0'` and `config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'`
3. pod install

I also set the iOS deployment target to be 12.0 in the PROJECT.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your answer. 
Before running as your suggestion, I want to ask if "Pods(no.1 step)" is a folder named "Pods" folder inside the 'ios' folder

Comment: Sadly this did not work for me. I tried 3 times but I still get the error: `Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): No such module 'FBSDKCoreKit'`

Comment: @SamHeyman Im so sad, too. I gave up about the ios and developing only android first now... did you solve it?

Comment: @user16330449, no sadly not, still stuck. I am surprised that there isn't more help available given that it is Facebook.

Comment: @SamHeyman ok. If I find a way, I'll share it here. Cheer up!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/darwin-morocho/flutter-facebook-auth/issues/299

I modified my Podfile

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
and config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0' (in my case, both version were not same. 11.0 <-> 9.0)
```

and the error changed like below:

```
FIRStorageTypedefs.h:29:19: note: declaration here is not visible
    typedef NSString *FIRStorageHandle NS_SWIFT_NAME(StorageHandle);
```

So I did pod uninstall, update, install, update, install..... T___T

```
arch -x86_64 pod update
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

and change the version of these like this

```
  firebase_auth: 4.1.0
  firebase_core: 2.1.1
  cloud_firestore: 4.0.3
  firebase_storage: 11.0.3
  firebase_messaging: 14.0.3
  cloud_functions: 4.0.3
  firebase_remote_config: 3.0.3
```

Addition:

1. my command line tools of Xcode are already installed

```
$xcode-select --install
error: command line tools are already installed
```

2. install ffi.. all failed

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
sudo arch -arm64 gem pristine ffi
```

Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,

in the podfile was: 
platform :ios, '13.0 
... 
config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'

in **config.build_settings** I changed the version from 9.0 to 13.0

and it helped